# Vector of Object Pointers, general help and confusion

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector

Have a homework assignment in which I'm supposed to create a vector of pointers to objects

Later on down the load, I'll be using inheritance/polymorphism to extend the class to include fees for two-day delivery, next day air, etc. However, that is not my concern right now. The final goal of the current program is to just print out every object's content in the vector (name & address) and find it's shipping cost (weight*cost).

My Trouble is not with the logic, I'm just confused on few points related to objects/pointers/vectors in general. But first my code. I basically cut out everything that does not mater right now, int  main, will have user input, but right now I hard-coded two examples.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Package {
public:
    Package(); //default constructor
    Package(string d_name, string d_add, string d_zip, string d_city, string d_state, double c, double w);
    double calculateCost(double, double);
    ~Package();

private:    
    string dest_name;
    string dest_address;
    string dest_zip;
    string dest_city;
    string dest_state;
    double weight;
    double cost;

};

Package::Package()
{
    cout<<"Constucting Package Object with default values: "<<endl;
    string dest_name="";
    string dest_address="";
    string dest_zip="";
    string dest_city="";
    string dest_state="";
    double weight=0;
    double cost=0;
}
Package::Package(string d_name, string d_add, string d_zip, string d_city, string d_state, string r_name, string r_add, string r_zip, string r_city, string r_state, double w, double c){

    cout<<"Constucting Package Object with user defined values: "<<endl;
    string dest_name=d_name;
    string dest_address=d_add;
    string dest_zip=d_zip;
    string dest_city=d_city;
    string dest_state=d_state;
    double weight=w;
    double cost=c;
}
Package::~Package()
{
    cout<<"Deconstructing Package Object!"<<endl;
    delete Package;
}
double Package::calculateCost(double x, double y){
    return x+y;
}
int main(){
    double cost=0;
    vector<Package*> shipment;
    cout<<"Enter Shipping Cost: "<<endl;
    cin>>cost;
    shipment.push_back(new Package("tom r","123 thunder road", "90210", "Red Bank", "NJ", cost, 10.5));
    shipment.push_back(new Package ("Harry Potter","10 Madison Avenue", "55555", "New York", "NY", cost, 32.3));
    return 0;

}
```

So my questions are:

1. I'm told I have to use a vector
   of Object Pointers, not Objects.
   Why? My assignment calls for it
   specifically, but I'm also told it
   won't work otherwise.
2. Where should I be creating this
   vector?
       Should it be part of my Package
       Class? How do I go about adding
       objects into it then?
3. Do I need a copy constructor? Why?
4. What's the proper way to deconstruct
   my vector of object pointers?

Any help would be appreciated. I've searched for a lot of related articles on here and I realize that my program will have memory leaks. Using one of the specialized ptrs from boost:: will not be available for me to use. Right now, I'm more concerned with getting the foundation of my program built. That way I can actually get down to the functionality I need to create.

Thanks.

Comment: *Side note* The destructor in `Package` is wrong and won't compile. Did you try to compile it?

Comment: I actually took it out to get it to compile. Forgot to do so in this code example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A vector of pointers can be reused for storing objects of sub-classes:

```
class Person
{
    public:
    virtual const std::string& to_string () = 0;
    virtual ~Person () { } 
};

class Student : public Person
{
   const std::string& to_string ()
   {
       // return name + grade
   }
};

class Employee : public Person
{
   const std::string& to_string ()
   {
      // return name + salary
   }
};

std::vector<Person*> persons;
person.push_back (new Student (name, grade));
person.push_back (new Employee (name, salary));
person[0]->to_string (); // name + grade
person[1]->to_string (); // name + salary
```

Ideally the vector should be wrapped up in a class. This makes memory management easier. It also facilitates changing the support data structure (here an `std::vector`) without breaking existing client code:

```
class PersonList
{
   public:
   Person* AddStudent (const std::string& name, int grade)
   {
       Person* p = new Student (name, grade);
       persons.push_back (p);
       return p;
   }

   Person* AddEmployee (const std::string& name, double salary)
   {
       Person* p = new Employee (name, salary);
       persons.push_back (p);
       return p;
   }
    
   ~PersonList ()
   {
      size_t sz = persons.size ();
      for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
          delete persons[i];
   }

   private
   std::vector<Person*> persons;
};
```

So we can re-write our code as:

```
{
   PersonList persons;
   Person* student = persons.AddStudent (name, grade);
   Person* employee = persons.AddEmployee (name, salary);
   student.to_string ();
   employee.to_string ();
} // The memory allocated for the Person objects will be deleted when
  // `persons` go out of scope here.
```

Getting familiar with the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) will help you decide when to add a copy constructor to a class. Also read about [const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html).

Comment: To use Person as a base class it should have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: 
You mentioned inheritance. Since inherited objects often need more bytes of storage, they don't fit into the place of a base object. If you try to put them in, you get a base object instead. This is called object slicing.

Question 2:
Design first, before you write code. There are a bunch of possible solutions.
For a start you can keep it in main(), but later you will be forced to make a class like `PackageContainer` for holding your objects.

Question 3 + 4:
You need a copy constructor, an assignment operator= and a destructor, when a class object owns dynamically allocated objects (the Rule of the Big Three). So a `PackageContainer` will probably need them.
You create objects dynamically using `new Object(..)`. You are responsible for destroying them and for giving their memory back to the system immediately before your vector of pointers is destroyed:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < shipment.size(); ++i)
{
  delete shipment[i];
}
```

Since working with naked pointers to dynamically allocated objects is not safe, consider using

```
std::vector<tr1::shared_ptr<Package> > shipment;
```

instead or

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Package> > shipment;
```

if your compiler understands C++0x. The `shared_ptr` handles freeing memory for you: It implements the Rule of the Big Three for one object pointer. It should be used in production quality code.

But try to get it right with naked pointers also. I think that's what your homework assignment is about.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe this is just a gap of knowledge of mine when it comes to classes/objects, but I'm not quite sure how my int main() would populate a vector defined in the class? Wouldn't I just create another vector for each object created then? Also, using my example, doesn't a class require all it's members to be passed to it for construction? For example, I'm passing name, weight, address, to create each object? How/why would I be passing to it from int main()? Should the vector maybe have public access within my class then? Thanks

Comment: @Staypuft: A class doesn't require to get constructor parameters for all members, but it should initialize all of them to guarantee a valid object state. When encapsulating data objects inside a class, to put information into them and to get it back you have to design accessor and modifier methods appropriate to what you want to express. So main() takes only objects of the highest abstraction level in your program. They send "messages" to each other to achieve your goal. Try to get a good book on C++ like Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in C++". If you are lucky, you can find some online.

Answer (score 1):

***I'm told I have to use a vector of Object Pointers, not Objects. Why? My assignment calls for it specifically, but I'm also told it won't work otherwise.***

Usually, one would avoid using vector of objects to avoid the problem of **[*Object Slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)**. To make polymorphism work You have to use some kind of pointers. I am not sure of how the classes in your assignment are aligned but probably you might have Inheritance there somewhere and hence if vector is storing objects of Base class and you insert objects of Derived class in it then it would cause the derived class members to slice off.

The Best solution will be to use a smart pointer instead of a Raw pointer. The STL has an `auto_ptr`, but that cannot be used in a standard container.Boost smart pointers would be a best solution but as you already said you can't use Boost So in your case you can use your compiler's implementation of smart pointers, which comes in `TR1` namespace,remember though that there is some disagreement on the namespace for TR1 functions (Visual C++ puts them in `std::`, while GCC puts them in `std::tr1::`).

***Where should I be creating this vector? Should it be part of my Package Class? How do I go about adding objects into it then?***
Your example code already has an example of adding a pointer to `Package` class in a vector. In a nutshell you will dynamically allocate pointers to `Package` and then add them to the vector.

***Do I need a copy constructor? Why?***
The copy constructor generated by the compiler does member-wise copying. Sometimes that is not sufficient. For example:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass( const char* str );
        ~MyClass();
    private:
        char* str;
    };

    MyClass::MyClass( const char* str2 )
    {
        str = new char[srtlen( str2 ) + 1 ];
        strcpy( str, str2 );
    }

    Class::~Class()
    {
        delete[] str;
    }
```

In this case member-wise copying of `str` member will not duplicate the buffer (only the pointer will be copied(`shallow copy`)), so the first to be destroyed copy sharing the buffer will call `delete[]` successfully and the second will run into `Undefined Behavior`. You need `deep copying copy constructor` (and assignment operator as well) in such a scenario.

When to use a custom copy constructor is best defined by the ***[Rule Of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)***:

```
Whenever you are writing either one of Destructor, Copy Constructor or Copy Assignment Operator, you probably need to write the other two.
```

***What's the proper way to deconstruct my vector of object pointers?***
You will have to explicitly call delete on each contained pointer to delete the content it is pointing to.

`vector::erase`
Removes from the vector container and calls its destructor but If the contained object is a pointer it doesnt take ownership of destroying it.

Check out [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353149/does-vectorerase-destroy-the-removed-object/6353169#6353169) here to know how to corrctly delete a vector of pointer to objects.