# when you push_back heap-allocated char into a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, cstring

I'm having trouble inserting char* into a vector< char*>

When I do the following:

```
string str = "Hello b World d"
char *cstr, *p;
vector<char*> redn;
cstr = new char [ (str.size)+1 ];
strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());

//here I tokenize "Hello b World d"
p = strtok(cstr," ");  
while(p!=NULL){
    redn.push_back(p);
    cout << "just pushed back: " << redn.back() << endl;
    p = strtok(NULL," ");
}
delete[] cstr;

//now check

for(it= redn.begin(); it < redn.end(); it++)
     cout << *it << endl;
```

I got an output of:

```
just pushed back: Hello
just pushed back: b
just pushed back: World
just pushed back: d
p0s

World
d
```

It seems to me that *it is pointing to the wrong thing..
Would anybody tell me what's going on and how I could fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***What is wrong in your code?***

Other answers explain you how to do it in a better way. My answer explains why your code doesn't work as you expected it to and a quick fix to get it working.

With the statement:

```
delete[] cstr;
```

You delete the string after you push the object in to the vector, this causes your vector elements to point to something that has already been de-allocated.

comment out that line and check again, it will work.

Here is the [**working sample**](http://www.ideone.com/WoLE1) of your code on Ideone.

Your vector in this case needs to take the ownership of deleting each of the contained object pointer which points to a dynamically allocated memory space.

See **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353149/does-vectorerase-destroy-the-removed-object/6353169#6353169)** for how to do that.

Comment: +1 for answering the question and not beating around the bush

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just use `vector<std::string>`? It would look like this then:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "Hello b World d";
    std::stringstream stream(s);
    std::vector<std::string> tokens(
        (std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream)),
        (std::istream_iterator<std::string>()));
    for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = tokens.begin();
        it != tokens.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For STL iterators use the following syntax:

```
vector<char*>::iterator it;
for(it= redn.begin(); 
    it != redn.end(); 
    ++it)
{
   cout << *it << endl;
}
```

(notice the ++it boost the algorithm performance)