# Alignment, STL vector and bullet physics aligned allocator

Tags: c++, performance, vector, stl, alignment

When I use this, I guess it's safe to say those objects are aligned:

```
std::vector<object_type> vect;
```

I spotted an allocator in bullet physics, and I don't know how they work. This also raises the question about std::vector.

In the demo here, line 42, http://code.google.com/p/bullet/source/browse/trunk/Demos/BasicDemo/BasicDemo.h#42

```
btAlignedObjectArray<btCollisionShape*> m_collisionShapes;
```

the type is a pointer, and later those pointer are assigned a `new`. Does it really guarantee alignment ? If the allocator is made to deal with pointers, I guess yes, but I don't have any allocator knowledge, on top of that I don't know what is obsolete or not.

What about `std::vector` ? If I declare

```
std::vector<object_type*> vect;
```

and assign later, will the compiler still align my objects ?

Comment: Question very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053157/will-this-code-make-those-vector-aligned

Comment: What alignment? 4-byte-alignment? 8-byte-alignment? 4KiB-alignment? Or are you misusing the term alignment?

Comment: alignment for caching purpose

Answer (score 1):

The *pointers* will be aligned contiguously in this vector of *pointers*. For the objects these pointers point to, nothing can be said. They may be placed anywhere.

A striking example would be

```
object_type on_stack;
vect[0] = new object_type;
vect[1] = & on_stack;
vect[2] = new object_type;
```

where the first and third element of the vector are assigned pointers to objects instantiated with `new` on the heap, while the second element is assigned the address of yet another instance on the stack.

If you wish to "align" *N* objects on the heap, there is still `new object_type[N];`

Comment: Or just `std::vector<object_type> v(N);`

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean, will the elements be *packed* contiguously?

Yes, they are guaranteed to be.

Comment: the objects ? or just the pointers ? Because I don't care about aligning pointers (or should I ?)

Comment: Only the pointers. The "elements" in this case are of pointer type. The objects can be allocated anywhere.

Comment: Pointers are objects too. The elements of your container are packed contiguously, which is what I already said.