# Vector:clear/pop_back won't run destructor

Tags: c++, vector, destructor, irrlicht

I have a vector (pflist) of "Pictureframe"s, and I want to destroy all of them. So I run pflist.clear(); The documentation says that this runs the destructor of each item in the vector, but it isn't!

I have a:

```
vector<Pictureframe*> pflist;
```

And here's the rest:

```
class Pictureframe{
    scene::IMeshSceneNode *picture;
    scene::IMeshSceneNode *frame;

public:
    Pictureframe();
    ~Pictureframe();
};
```

and then in the cpp file:

```
Pictureframe::~Pictureframe(){
//  delete picture;
//  delete frame;
    cout<<"Destructor Called.\n\n";
}
```

There is nary a "Destructor Called" in sight! Here's where I call it:

```
pflist.clear();
```

I am sure that this line is being run, and that is populated by 5 pictureframes. I also tried a for loop that went through the vector pop_back'ing, and that had the same problem.

So Destructor, Y U NO CALL?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a vector of `PictureFrame*`?

Comment: What is the type of your vector? Is it `vector<Pictureframe>` or `vector<Pictureframe *>`?

Comment: I'll adjust the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question doesn't state what the type of the `std::vector` is. If the type is `std::vector<Pictureframe *>` then the destructors of each element will not be called when you call `std::vector::clear`. In this case it is your responsibility to `delete` these objects ***before*** clearing the vector.

If you don't need to dynamically allocate these objects, change the vector type to `std::vector<Pictureframe>`. Use it as:

```
std::vector<Pictureframe> vec;
vec.push_back( Pictureframe( ... ) );
// do stuff
vec.clear();
```

Now the destructor for each object will be called. Remember to create a copy constructor and assignment operator for `Pictureframe` since it looks like the class is managing some resources.

If you must dynamically allocate `Pictureframe` objects, change the vector to

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pictureframe>> vec;
vec.push_back( std::unique_ptr<Pictureframe>( new Pictureframe( ... ) ) );
// do stuff
vec.clear();
```

`unique_ptr` will automatically `delete` the objects in this case.

Other alternatives are `boost::shared_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr` or [`boost::ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the thoroughness of this answer, you were spot on, and its fixed! Muchos Gracias Senor

Comment: More correctly, the destructor of each element in the container _will_ be run.  The destructor of a pointer is a no-op, however.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty much sure you have an `std::vector<Pictureframe *>`
Any standard library container does not take the responsibility of clearing dynamically allocated pointer elements.

You will have to iterate through the `std::vector` and call `delete` on each of the elements.

This answer of mine to an old question should be a good read:
[**Does vector::erase() destroy the removed object?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353149/does-vectorerase-destroy-the-removed-object/6353169#6353169)