# Deleting element from a vector of lists C++

Tags: c++, list, vector, stdlist

I have a class that has a std::list as a member variable. I also have a vector of these classes. If I delete an element from the vector, will the class destructor be called on the deleted instance? Do I have to explicitly clear my list with list::clear() in the destructor?

```
class my_class {
    string class_name;
    list<int> my_list;
public: 
    my_class(); 
    ~my_class(); // destructor
};

vector<my_class> my_vec;

my_class obj1, obj2, obj3;
my_vec.push_back(obj1);
my_vec.push_back(obj2);
my_vec.push_back(obj3);

my_vec.erase(my_vec.begin()+2); //Is this sufficient?
```

Comment: here is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353149/does-vectorerase-on-a-vector-of-object-pointers-destroy-the-object-itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` follows the [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) principle, which ensures that the object's destructor is called and the object is deleted from memory once the object goes out of scope.

Specifically to your questions:

**If I delete an element from the vector, will the class destructor be called on the deleted instance?** Yes

**Do I have to explicitly clear my list with list::clear() in the destructor?** No

**Be aware:** RAII doesn't do *anything* with pointers. So, it does not dereference a pointer, nor does it call the destructor on the dereferenced object, nor does it delete the dereferenced object from memory.

Comment: Ok, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26794869/8487921) sounds like, the counter of the shared pointer will be decremented.