# how to delete a shared pointer value in vector

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have type defined a shared pointer as :  `typedef shared_ptr<Myclass> Sptr;`

then a vector                           :   `vector<Sptr> vectr`;

now I have stored several shared pointers in a vector, each is pointing to a dynamically allocated memory.

now I want to delete particular element(child) in a vector(children.begin() to children.end()).

```
ItemList::iterator it = find(children.begin(), children.end(), child);
if (it != children.end())
{
    //delete it;
    it = children.erase(it);
}
```

Now children.erase(it), will this delete the memory which is dynamically allocated and pointed by the pointer inside shared pointer. (only the shared pointer which is in vector pointing to the dynamic memory i.e count is 1)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean `typedef shared_ptr<Myclass> Sptr;` instead of `typedef shared_ptr<Myclass*> Sptr;` ?

Comment: @billz sorry, it typedef shared_ptr<Myclass> Sptr.

Comment: Thanks.. one more thing if I do  like below    vectr[index] = sharedPtr;  will the old value at index will be deleted ??

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  If the only instance of a shared pointer is the instance in the vector, then erasing it out of the vector will lead to the destructor for that shared pointer instance running.  And that will free the associated memory for the object the shared pointer owns.

*If you know the reference count is one... BUT...*

...one of the reasons to use a shared pointer is precisely that you *don't know* when something is the last instance.  If you have that much knowledge...and this vector is the "owning" collection, then consider alternatives like [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: Thanks.. one more thing if I do  like below    vectr[index] = sharedPtr;  will the old value at index will be deleted ??

Comment: @Durga You can reason through the answer to that under the basics of how C++ works.  Remember that a shared_ptr instance is just an object...it's an object you could have written yourself.  Its instance takes up some memory and has a reference count.  You can't put the new object into the vector slot without getting rid of the old object, and every time you "get rid" of things in C++ a destructor runs.  You're not moving or preserving the shared_ptr instance that is being overwritten...so what would you say needs to happen?

Comment: before it was like, vector of pointers vector<ptr*>; then in my project, the are deleting the object as delete vector[index] (will delete dynamically allocated memory), then pointing with new value vector[index] = newValue;   now I have to replace the same thing with shared pointers.  I commented the delete vector[index] line, then I simply did  vector[index] = newSharedObj; will this delete the old memory ??

Comment: @Durga Your typedefs continue to confuse the question.  You have not anywhere defined `ptr` in this discussion; you only defined `Sptr`.  Computer code is precise, and Q&A here is not a mind-reading exercise, so use as much precision as possible if you have a question.  But if you are taking code based on `vector<Myclass*>` that used to need to explicitly delete the Myclass* prior to vector removal, and shifting it to use `vector<shared_ptr<Myclass>>`, then indeed no delete will be necessary.  Please also heed my advice about ownership control via unique_ptr.

Answer (score 2):

When a `shared_ptr` is deleted, it deletes the object to which it holds a pointer if and only if that's the last `shapred_ptr` that holds a pointer to the object. If another `shared_ptr` holds a pointer to the object, the object is not deleted.

You should see the same behavior when you remove `shared_ptr`s from your `vector`.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct A
{
   ~A() {std::cout << "Came to ~A()\n";}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   std::shared_ptr<A> ptr1(new A());
   std::shared_ptr<A> ptr2(new A());

   {
      std::cout << "In the nested scope\n"; 
      std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> ptrList;
      ptrList.push_back(ptr1);
      ptrList.push_back(ptr2);
   }

   std::cout << "Out of the nested scope\n"; 

   return 0;
}
```

OUtput:

```
In the nested scope
Out of the nested scope
Came to ~A()
Came to ~A()
```