# Does std::vector call the destructor of pointers to objects?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, vector, destructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting pointers in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061438/deleting-pointers-in-a-vector)

I know when an `std::vector` is destructed, it will call the destructor of each of its items. Does it call the destructor of *pointers* to objects?

```
vector<myclass*> stuff;
```

When stuff is destroyed, do the individual objects pointed to by the pointers inside stuff get destructed?

Comment: Check out [boost::ptr_vector<my_class>](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html)

Answer (score 36):

No.

How is `std::vector` supposed to know how to destroy the pointed-to object?  Should it use `delete`?  `delete[]`?  `free`?  Some other function?  How is it supposed to know the pointed-to objects are actually dynamically allocated or that it is the One True Owner and is responsible for destroying them?

If the `std::vector` is the One True Owner of the pointed-to objects, use `std::unique_ptr`, potentially with a custom deleter to handle the cleanup of the objects.

Comment: If `std::vector` would have a constructor that takes a destruction function for the elements that would be dandy. It would be useful for legacy or C API. But anyhow the better way of doing things is wrapping this sort of resources with a RAII class.

Comment: @wilhelmtell you can write a custom allocator for that :) Or give `unique_ptr` a custom deleter function.

Comment: @SethCarnegie yeah, it hit me seconds after posting the comment. happens to me all the time, talking before thinking. :-S

Answer (score 22):

As you said correctly yourself, vector does call destructors for its elements. So, in your example the vector **does** call "destructors of pointers". However, you have to keep in mind that pointer types have no destructors. Only class types can have destructors. And pointers are not classes. So, it is more correct to say that `std::vector` applies the pseudo-destructor call syntax to the pointer objects stored in the vector. For pointer types that results in no-operation, i.e it does nothing.

This also answers the second part of your question: whether the `myclass` objects pointed by the pointers get destroyed. No, they don't get destroyed.

Also, it seems that you somehow believe that "calling destructors on pointers" (the first part of your question) is the same thing as "destroying the pointed objects" (the second part of your question). In reality these are two completely different unrelated things.

In order to create a link from the former to the latter, i.e. to make the vector destroy the pointed objects, you need to build your vector from some sort of "smart pointers", as opposed to ordinary raw `myclass *` pointers. The vector will automatically call the destructors of the "smart pointers" and these destructors, in turn, will destroy the pointed objects. This "link" can only be implemented explicitly, inside the "smart pointer's" destructor, which is why ordinary raw pointers can't help you here.

Comment: Actually if you want to be precise, `std::vector` does not destruct anything, the allocator does

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it shows why pointers are no special case.

Answer (score 6):

No; what if you stored a pointer to an automatic object?

```
vector<T*> v;
T tinst;
v.push_back(&tinst);
```

If the vector calls the destructors of the objects the pointers point to, the automatic object would be destructed twice - once when it went out of scope, and once when the vector went out of scope. Also, what if they are not supposed to be deallocated with `delete`? There's no way it could behave appropriately in every situation.

If your objects are all allocated dynamically, you have to manually iterate the vector and `delete` each pointer if it was allocated with `new`. Alternatively, you can create a vector of smart pointers which *will* deallocate the objects pointed to by the pointers:

```
vector<shared_ptr<T>> v;
v.push_back(new T);
```

Comment: Hm. I think the second word, "because", is misleading. The onus to justify not deleting pointees is not on the vector; rather, the OP must explain why a container *should* treat pointer-typed elements differently. As it stands, the answer could be a simple, "No.".