# Program crashes when calling destructor on object with a vector matrix of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

I have a `class` which is basically a wrapper for a `2D matrix` of pointers to another object, and the matrix is made of `vectors`.

For some reason, the program crashes whenever the destructor of my `class` is being called, and it seems like it's trying to `delete` the pointers even if they are `nullptr`, which causes a crash.

Here are my `.h` and `.cpp` file:

**cpp file:**

`RotationSolution.h`:

```
#ifndef PUZZLESOLVER_ROTATIONSOLUTION_H
#define PUZZLESOLVER_ROTATIONSOLUTION_H

#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include "PuzzlePiece.h"

using namespace std;

class RotationSolution {
private:
    int _height, _width;
    vector<vector<PuzzlePiece*>> _matrix;

public:
    RotationSolution();

    RotationSolution(int height, int width);

    vector<PuzzlePiece*>& operator[](int row);

    int get_height() const;

    int get_width() const;
};


#endif //PUZZLESOLVER_ROTATIONSOLUTION_H
```

**RotationSolution.cpp:**

```
#include "RotationSolution.h"

vector<PuzzlePiece*>& RotationSolution::operator[](int row) {
    return _matrix[row];
}

RotationSolution::RotationSolution() : RotationSolution(0, 0) {}

RotationSolution::RotationSolution(int height, int width) :
    _height(height), _width(width), _matrix(vector<vector<PuzzlePiece*>>(_height, vector<PuzzlePiece*>(_width, nullptr)))
{}

int RotationSolution::get_height() const {
    return _height;
}

int RotationSolution::get_width() const {
    return _width;
}
```

The code is actually crashing in a section that looks like this:

```
    for (auto length: _rowLengths) {
        auto height = size / length;
        _sol = RotationSolution(height, length);

        ...
    }
```

in the second iteration in the `_sol = RotationSolution(height, length);` line.

When debugging, the code the sends the crash signal is from `new_allocator.h` (which I'm pretty sure is a lib file):

```
  // __p is not permitted to be a null pointer.
  void
  deallocate(pointer __p, size_type)
  { ::operator delete(__p); }
```

I am still new to `c++` so please forgive any noob mistakes and bad practices :)

Comment: Why the downvote? please tell me if there's anything missing

Comment: Did you miss to paste all your code? You don't even *have* a destructor. How can it crash in there?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I am using the default destructor, I thought it's implied

Comment: delete operator is not called when vector contains pointer, the problem is not this place, paste more code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that something calls it... please look at my addition @rafix07

Comment: @TomerAmir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448260/does-stdvector-call-the-destructor-of-pointers-to-objects

Comment: Post the code of `RotationSolution`.

Comment: So what calls it? Go up the callstack and check.

Comment: @rafix07 so should I write my own destructor? this class is not the owner of the pointers, so I would like it to just leave them alone when destructing.

Sorry again for the noob questions

Comment: We can't compile this on our machines. Please provide a [mcve]. Without it it's a guessing game. What is `PuzzlePiece.h`?

Comment: @Ron PuzzlePiece simple data class. I'll try to upload a complete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a design flaw in RotationSolution class - it contains member variable _matrix which stores raw pointers and it misses properly defined assigment operator which will clone objects stored inside _matrix. [Default generated copy assigment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) will just copy pointers which may lead to double freeing memory and crash ([here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/assignment-operators) is some explanations what is happening and why). Try to use "vector< vector< std::shared_ptr< PuzzlePiece > > > _matrix" (also do #include "memory") it should fix most of problems with wrong memory management. Here is [tutorial](https://mbevin.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/smart-pointers/) to read about smart pointers.

Comment: Sound like my problem. I do the `operator=` in my call stack. still not sure how to fix though, but this seems like the problem. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, in my comment text got messed somehow. try to use std::shared_ptr<PuzzlePiece> type instead of PuzzlePiece* inside vector template declaration, it should help resolve problem with assigments. to instanitate PuzzlePiece object you could use std::make_shared<PuzzlePiece>(... constructor parameters go here ...)